# How to extend JavaScript countdown timer function with a new method?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following countdown timer function:

```js
jQuery.fn.countDown = function(settings,to) {
    settings = jQuery.extend({
                                startFontSize: "46px",
                                endFontSize: "18px",
                                duration: 1000,
                                endNumber: 0,
                                callBack: function() { }
                             },
                             settings);

    return this.each(function() {
        //where do we start?
        if(!to && to != settings.endNumber) { to = settings.startNumber; }

        //set the countdown to the starting number
        jQuery(this).text(to).css("fontSize",settings.startFontSize);

        //loopage
        jQuery(this).animate({fontSize: settings.endFontSize},
                             settings.duration,
                             "",
                             function() {
                                if(to > settings.endNumber + 1) {
                                    jQuery(this).css("fontSize",
                                    settings.startFontSize).text(to - 1).countDown(settings, to - 1);
                                } else {
                                    settings.callBack(this);
                                }
                             });
    });
};
```

To start a countdown on my page, I initialize it like so:

(This will make it count down from 5 to 0, shown in element #countdown)

```
jQuery("#countdown").countDown({
    startNumber: 5,
    callBack: function(me) { }
});
```

Now I sometimes need to cancel a running countdown and start a new one.

For example, stop the countdown at 3 and initialize again to start over.

Can somebody tell me how I can extend this code to do that?

(the original timer script was taken from http://davidwalsh.name/jquery-countdown-plugin)

V.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you have some access to the settings, and you execute your timer as such:

```
var settings = {
    startNumber: 5,
    callBack: function(me) {}
};
jQuery("#countdown").countDown(settings);
```

You can stop and restart your timer like this:

```
function stopAndRestart() {
    jQuery("#countdown").stop().countDown(settings);
}
```

[.stop()](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) stops the animation on a given element (which happens to, terribly, be the method of timing here)